# cycle-sort : why the outer most loop runs (n-1) times

Tags: sorting, cycle-sort

I was learning cycle-sort and get confused on why the outer loop of cycle-sort runs (n-1) times instead on n-times.(n is array size)

```
 for (int cycle_start=0; cycle_start< n-1; cycle_start++)
```

please explain. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a cycle-sort, the last item will be in the correct place, automatically, so you don't need to loop over it.